# Find RV distribution and prove its convergence to zero

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables, extreme-value-analysis

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of independent and uniformly distributed over $[0; 1]$ random variables. The task is to find distribution of the following random variable: $m_n=\min\{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n\}$ and also proof that it converges almost surely to zero, in other words: $$\Pr(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}m_n=0)=1$$

Comment: Have you tried explicitly writing out $Pr(m_n \leq u)$ for $u \in [0, 1]$? Densities of the $m_n$ exist.

Comment: @vandenheuvel, I've got that $P(m_n<t)=1-[1-F(t)]^n$, where F is CDF of $m_n$. That's all for now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $x\in[0,1]$ we have
$$
\left\{\min_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n} X_i \geqslant x \right\} = \bigcap_{i=1}^n \{X_i\geqslant x\}.
$$
It follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(m_n\geqslant x) &= \mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n \{X_i\geqslant x\} \right)\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb P(X_i\geqslant x)\\
&= \mathbb P(X_1\geqslant x)^n\\
&= (1-x)^n,
\end{align}
and so the distribution function of $m_n$ is
$$
F_n = (1 - (1-x)^n)\cdot\mathsf 1_{[0,1]}(x) + \mathsf 1_{(1,\infty)}(x)
$$
and the density
$$
f_n = n(1-x)^{n-1}\cdot\mathsf 1_{[0,1]}(x).
$$
Recall that $Z_n\to Z$ almost surely if and only if
$$
\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} \{|Z_n-Z|>\varepsilon\}\right) = 0
$$
for all $\varepsilon>0$. Let $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$, then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(m_n>\varepsilon) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-\varepsilon)^n = \frac{1-\varepsilon}\varepsilon<\infty,
$$
so by the Borel-Cantelli lemma
$$
\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} \{X_n>\varepsilon\}\right)=0,
$$
and hence $m_n\to 0$ almost surely.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\} \ge x \text{ if and only if } \big[X_1\ge x\ \& \cdots \ \&\ X_n\ge x\big].
$$
If you can find the probability of that, then that gives you the distribution of the minimum.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I've got that $P(m_n \leq t)=1-P(\{X_1>t\} \cap \{X_2>t\} ... \cap \{X_n>t\})=1-\big(1-F(t)\big)^n$, where F is $X_i$ CDF and $\forall X_i$ is equal to: $F_i(t)=Ind_{t \in [0;1]}*t$. However have no ideas about the limit..

Comment: @Gorhonm : Do you know what the c.d.f. of the uniform distribution is? $\qquad$

Comment: Sure, it is $F_X(t)=Pr(X \leq y)$, however I agree that indicator is not necessary. Instead it is easier to introduce c.f.d on sections: it is equal to 0 for $t \leq 0$, it is equal to $t$ for $t \in [0; 1]$, it is equal to $1$, for $t \geq 1$

Comment: @Gorhonm : "Sure, it is $F_X(t) = \Pr(X\le y).$" I'm sorry, but that is wrong. First, $F_X(t)$ is $\Pr(X\le t), $ not $\Pr(X\le y),$ but also, you stopped to early. $F_X(t) = \Pr(X\le t) = \text{a PARTICULAR function of $t$.}$ So the question was whether you know which function that is. $\qquad$